# Injected into a custom class logger in azure function does not write to console

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have Azure function V2 (IotHub trigger). If I use ILogger ingected into Main trigger function then log.Debug() outputs perfectly:

```
[FunctionName("MainFunc")]
public async Task Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "IotHubCompatibleEndpointConnectionString", ConsumerGroup = "iothub_trigger_sqldb_cg")]
    EventData eventData,
    ILogger log)
{

    log.LogDebug("it outputs!"); // works perfectly
```

What I want to do is to inject logger into my custom service:

```
public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ITelemetryProcessor, TelemetryProcessor>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<INotificationSender, NotificationSender>();
        builder.Services.AddLogging();
    }
}
```

In a service constructor I try to write log into output console in 2 ways

```
public TelemetryProcessor(INotificationSender notificationSender, ILogger<ITelemetryProcessor> log, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _notificationSender = notificationSender;
    _log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("common");
    _log.LogDebug("write something"); // doesn't output
    log.LogDebug("write something v2"); // doesn't output as well
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging should be set up in host.json
After adding the logging section the injected log (both) started working

For example like that:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "fileLoggingMode": "debugOnly",
    "logLevel": {
      // For all functions
      "Function": "Trace",
      // Default settings, e.g. for host
      "default": "Trace"
    }
  }
}
```

More on configuration can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json)

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify `[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]` attribute?

Here is a full working example of [logging to DataDog via Serilog from Azure Function](https://druss.co/2019/10/logging-datadog-azure-function-serilog/)

```
    private IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(
                    new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .WriteTo.DatadogLogs(
                            apiKey: "REPLACE - DataDog API Key",
                            host: Environment.MachineName,
                            source: "REPLACE - Log-Source",
                            service: GetServiceName(),
                            configuration: new DatadogConfiguration(),
                            logLevel: LogEventLevel.Infomation
                        )
                        .CreateLogger())
            );

        return services;
    }
```